# change one Array list item order relative to another

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

Ive got 2 Array lists

```
 ArrayList<String> passengerNames= new ArrayList<String>();//stores passenger names
ArrayList<String> seatNumber= new ArrayList<String>();//stores the seat passenger booked 1  seat=1passenger
    passengerNames.add("Ram");
    passengerNames.add("Shyam");
    passengerNames.add("CPS");
    passengerNames.add("John");
    passengerNames.add("Steve");

    seatNumber.add(1);
    seatNumber.add(84);
    seatNumber.add(19);
    seatNumber.add(99);
    seatNumber.add(78);
```

so the passengerNames array will be
[Ram, Shyam, CPS, John, Steve]
and seatNumber array will be 
[1, 84, 19, 99, 78]
I want to sort the seatNumber array in accending order but I want to change the passengerNames list with it as in when seatNumber is in accending order like
[1,19,78,84,99]
the passengerNames array should be sorted like
[Ram,CPS,Steve,Shyam,Jhon]

Comment: what is your question? "How to do it ?"

Comment: [Mod] - Please edit your question for a clearer more specific one, if needed please add relevant code samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it would be more appropriate to use a SortedMap

```
SortedMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(1, "Ram");
map.put(84, "Shyam");
map.put(19, "CPS");
map.put(99, "John");
map.put(78, "Steve");
```

You don't need to pass a Comparator in the constructor in your case, because you need the keys to be in ascendent order, that is their natural order. The cool thing is that they will be already sorted without doing anything, they will sort automatically as you add them

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest encapsulating your data in a new `Passenger` object and creating a single ArrayList of type Passenger - this should keep things tidy and flexible.

```
public class Passenger {
    private String name;
    private int seatNumber;

    public Passenger(String name, int seatNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.seatNumber = seatNumber;
    }
}
```

... and for creating the Passenger ArrayList

```
List<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<Passenger>(); // build Passenger ArrayList
passengers.add(new Passenger("Ram", 1)); // create new Passenger
passengers.add(new Passenger("Shyam", 84)); // etc...
```

In regards to sorting the List in ascending order, a clean approach is to `implement Comparable` in the `Passenger` class, and define the behavior in the `compareTo(Passenger p)` method. Once that is defined to your liking, the sort can be called via `Collections.sort(passengers);`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having two arrays of information that belong to a single entity, create an Object Passenger in which you assign the name and seat number.

```
public class Passenger {

    private String name;
    private int seatNumber;

    public Passenger(String name, int seatNumber){
        this.name = name;
        this.seatNumber = seatNumber;
    }
    // setters and getters
}
```

Now just create your array of passengers

```
ArrayList<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
passengers.add(new Passenger("Ram", 1));
```

Then use a sorting method by Object attribute.

```
Arrays.sort(passengers, Comparator.comparing(Passenger::getSeatNumber));
```